# Help Alice and Bob find common interests

Tags: knowledge, pattern, word-property

After their recent financial division our friends Alice and Bob thought they had seen the last of each other. To their surprise, they ran into each other over their winter holidays, both having unknowingly booked the same resort.

"I'm staying in 176, want to drop by for a game of checkers?" Bob asked.

Alice replied, "I'd rather go to the theater, but how about a game of *Skrabelle*? I'm in Cabin 87." *Skrabelle* is as you may know a public domain tiled word game.

The two meet up for a game; several minutes into it, Alice comments on Bob's word choices. "What unappealing words you've played, Bob: CANDIDATE, INTEGRITY, UNITED, CHARGE. The only one I like is PEOPLE."

"I was thinking the same thing of most of your choices, Alice," replied Bob. "SCORE, CONTINENT, DEDICATED, and ENDURE are all quite boring, though I will say that GOVERNMENT is appealing."

Alice and Bob finish their game having 20 words on the board, then take turns opining on the qualities of the words played. Some words only Alice likes, other words only Bob likes, and some words are liked by both (every word in the list is liked by at least one). Their likes are tabulated below.

| Word | Liked By |
| --- | --- |
| CANDIDATE | Bob |
| CHARGE | Bob |
| CIVIL | Alice |
| CONTINENT | Alice |
| DEDICATED | Alice |
| ENDURE | Alice |
| EQUAL | Alice |
| GOVERNMENT | Both Alice & Bob |
| GREAT | Both Alice & Bob |
| HALLOW | Alice |
| INDEPENDENT | Bob |
| INTEGRITY | Bob |
| PEOPLE | Both Alice & Bob |
| PORTION | Both Alice & Bob |
| SCORE | Alice |
| SEVEN | Both Alice & Bob |
| SPECIAL | Bob |
| UNITED | Bob |
| WAR | Both Alice & Bob |
| WRONG | Bob |

Can you help our friends Alice and Bob figure out the pattern to their word interests? What kinds of words are liked by Alice only, Bob only, or both? Can you find at least one other word they both like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One word they both like might be

> God

All of the words Alice likes

> are in Abraham Lincoln's 1863 [Gettysburg Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettysburg_Address).

All of the words Bob likes

> are in Richard Nixon's 1952 [Checkers Speech](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Checkers_speech).

Clues in the text

> Bob is staying in 176. Nixon's speech was 176 years after the founding of the USA. Alice is staying in cabin 87. Abraham Lincoln was born in a log cabin and his speech was given 87 ("four score and seven") years after the founding of the USA. Also Bob wanted to play Checkers and Alice wanted to go to the theater. (Abraham Lincoln was assassinated at the theater.)